# VSTS build running locally - error: "Microsoft Internet Explorer. Enhanced Security Configuration"

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm running Windows 10 and making a script to handle/start VSTS builds.

Sample call (overriding properties for testing):

```
$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI = "https://mytenancy.visualstudio.com/"
$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID = "Project1"
$env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID = 5
#$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN = "mytoken" - uncomment when running locally

$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/definitions/$($env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=2.0"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Definition = $($definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
"Authenticated"
```

This script works fine on the server, but if I uncomment the `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` and run locally, I get the following error:

> Microsoft Internet Explorer\u0026#39;s Enhanced Security Configuration
>   is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of
>   security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or
>   performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable
>   this configuration or contact your administrator.

I'm running Windows 10.

I've tried many things, including:

- Turning off as much security as possible in Internet Options.
- Fresh Token
- Converting the token to a secure string
- Converting to a Base64 string as detailed in the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498440/why-i-get-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-error-message-in-chrome-if-i-call)

How can I authenticate locally?

**EDIT (following accepted answer)**

The accepted answer solved the problem. I think the two key points here were:

- The correct encoding in conversion to Base64
- Changing authentication from `Bearer` to `Basic` when running in this way (locally).

Final code:

```
$user = "[username]"
$accessToken="[token]"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$accessToken)))
$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI = "https://mytenancy.visualstudio.com/"
$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID = "Project1"

$checkBuildUrl = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID)/_apis/build/builds/$($requestedBuildId)?api-version=2.0"

$buildStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $checkBuildUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new access token and refer to this code to call the REST API through PowerShell:

```
$user = "[anything]"
$accessToken="[access token]"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$accessToken)))
...
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $bodyJson
```

Regarding enhanced security, there is a similar issue:

*[Enhanced Security Error while Visual Studio Team Services Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644364/enhanced-security-error-while-visual-studio-team-services-rest-api)*